# How to save $(document).html() to a .xml file in jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to push a form button and save all the html in the document to a xml file.  Also If I have 3 frames or iFrames, I want to also save everything from my 2nd iframe id 'iframe2' (except the iframe itself) into a file, but have a dialog box pop up that says are you sure you want to save this file?

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is it would save me a step of writing xml to a file as well as displaying it in the browser.  If its not possible in html4.01 is it possible in html5?

I can look at the html using $('#iframe2').html();  but not sure how to save it.

Thanks

Comment: you can't write files with javascript from a browser, AFAIK

Comment: You know that it won't be a valid XML file right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Comment: Which browsers would you like to support? because `execCommand` is available in IE. Or use Flash solutions to generate files in browser using Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this as far as I know:

- You could use Flash or Java or another browser plugin to make a save file dialog (check out [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify))
- You could use data URIs (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/4551467#4551467). You'll want to change the mime type to `application/xml`)
- You could use the server to trigger an attachement download with the contents you want. That content could be transmitted through AJAX (check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445774/correct-way-to-trigger-a-file-download-in-php)).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a backend language like PHP to accept the string as POST data and write it to an XML file in one swoop.

```
if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to save this file?')) {
  $.post('/save.php', { 'html': $('#iframe2').html() }, function (_dta) {
    window.alert(_dta);
  });
}
```

and on PHP

```
<?php
$html = $_POST['html'];
file_put_contents('./iframe2.xml', $html);
echo 'saved!';
?>
```